# On the rank of a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on a scheme $X$. If $X$ is proper, then there exists a smallest integer $R$ such that $\mathrm{rank} \ F(x)\leqslant R$ for all $x$ in $X$. On the other hand there is also a maximal integer $r$ such that $r\leqslant\mathrm{rank} \ F(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$.

I call $F$ of type $(\ast)$ if for every integer $n$ in $[r,R]$ there exists a point $x$ such that $F(x)$ has rank $n$. It is clear that locally free sheaves satisfy $(\ast)$; on the other hand there are sheaves which do not satisfy $(\ast)$, e.g. take $F=\mathcal{O}_p^{\oplus 2}$, where $p$ is a point.

Is there a description of the class of sheaves satisfying $(\ast)$? What are some nice (non-locally free) sheaves satisfying $(\ast)$. E.g. does the cotangent sheaf $\Omega_X$ satisfy $(\ast)$?

Comment: If I understood your notation, no, in general cotangent sheaves do not satisfy your condition. As an example, take the cone over the Veronese embedding of the projective line in projective space of large dimension. Then, the cotangent sheaf has rank 2 at all points but the vertex of the cone and you can arrange it to have as high rank as you want at the vertex.

Comment: When you say proper do you mean over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Mohan my notation $(\ast)$ means that the rank of the sheaf $F$ takes on all values it possibly can ("no gaps"). Thanks for your example, it is instructive!

Comment: @diracdeltafunk I think I implicitly assume that there is some ground field, and $X$ should be proper over that field. But that assumption is not so important

Comment: What about the case where $X = \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C})$? $X$ is proper over $\mathbb{C}$, and topologically $X$ is the discrete space on two points. Each coherent sheaf on $X$ is therefore constructed by choosing a finite-dimensional $\mathbb{C}$-vector space over each point, and all of these sheaves are locally free. Since we can choose the dimensions of each stalk arbitrarily, we can easily produce a locally free sheaf on $X$ which does not satisfy $(*)$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk thats basically the same example as i gave!

Comment: I am confused about what you mean by "it is clear that locally free sheaves satisfy $(*)$" since this is an example of a locally free sheaf which does not satisfy $(*)$. For that matter, I was also confused about what scheme $\mathcal{O}_p^{\oplus 2}$ is supposed to be on – every coherent sheaf on a point $p$ must satisfy $(*)$! If this was supposed to be a sheaf on two points, it seems like it satisfies $(*)$ anyway, since the rank at each of the two points will be $1$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk well, I was implicitly assuming that $X$ be irreducible (otherwise there are obvious counterexamples). $\mathcal{O}_p^{\oplus 2}$ has rank $2$ at $p$ and zero elsewhere (skyscraper sheaf), in particular cannot have rank $1$ at some point, so does not satisfy $(\ast)$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand your post now, thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk you are welcome!